# How do I show only some dates in range on x-axis in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

When I draw the graph, it is unreadable as in the image because all the dates in the data are written on the x-axis. I am trying to make only some of the dates (eg 90 days apart) written. The data set is from 2012-11-07 to 2022-11-04 so there is a lot of data.

code:

```
ticker <- "AMAT"


price_data <- returns_long %>% filter(Ticker == ticker, Series == "Close")

price_chart <- ggplot(price_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value, group=1), color = "#66CC00") +
  xlab("Date") +
  ylab("Stock Price") +
  labs(
    title = paste0(price_data$Name[1], " (", ticker, ")"),
    subtitle = price_data$Sector[1],
    caption = "Source: Yahoo! Finance"
  )+
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  theme(
    
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#17202A"),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#17202A"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(color = "#ffffff", angle = 45, hjust = 1, vjust = 1),
    axis.text.y = element_text(color = "#ffffff"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(color = "#ffffff"),
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "#ffffff"),
    plot.title = element_text(color = "#ffffff"),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(color = "#ffffff"),
    plot.caption = element_text(color = "#ffffff", face = "italic", size = 6),
    panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "#273746"),
    panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor.y = element_blank(),
    legend.position = "none",
    
  )
price_chart
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Use [`scale_x_date()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/scale_date.html) with the `date_breaks` argument. e.g.,

```
library(ggplot2)

price_chart <- ggplot(price_data) +
  geom_line(aes(x = Date, y = Value, group=1), color = "#66CC00") +
  labs(
    x = "Date",
    y = "Stock Price",
    title = paste0(price_data$Name[1], " (", ticker, ")"),
    subtitle = price_data$Sector[1],
    caption = "Source: Yahoo! Finance"
  ) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::dollar) +
  scale_x_date(date_breaks = "90 days") +
  theme(
    # as in OP
  )
```

[image]

You may also want to experiment with the `date_labels` or `labels` args. e.g., `date_labels = "%b %Y"` will give you `"May 2012"` instead of `"2012-05-20"`; `labels = ~ lubridate::quarter(.x, type = "year.quarter")` will give you quarters as `"2012.1"`, `"2012.2"`, etc.

*Example data:*

```
set.seed(13)

price_data <- data.frame(
  Date = seq(as.Date("2012-11-07"), as.Date("2022-11-04"), by = 1),
  Value = 50 + cumsum(rnorm(3650)),
  Name = rep("Applied Materials", 3650),
  Sector = rep("Information Technology", 3650)
)
```